# Using the GPU on iOS for Overlaying one image on another Image (Video Frame)

Tags: ios, opengl, opengl-es

I am working on some image processing in my app. Taking live video and adding an image onto of it to use it as an overlay. Unfortunately this is taking massive amounts of CPU to do which is causing other parts of the program to slow down and not work as intended. Essentially I want to make the following code use the GPU instead of the CPU.

```
- (UIImage *)processUsingCoreImage:(CVPixelBufferRef)input {

    CIImage *inputCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:input];


// Use Core Graphics for this
UIImage * ghostImage = [self createPaddedGhostImageWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)];//[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
CIImage * ghostCIImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:ghostImage];

CIFilter * blendFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceAtopCompositing"];
[blendFilter setValue:ghostCIImage forKeyPath:@"inputImage"];
[blendFilter setValue:inputCIImage forKeyPath:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

CIImage * blendOutput = [blendFilter outputImage];

EAGLContext *myEAGLContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
NSDictionary *contextOptions = @{ kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null] ,[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]:kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer};
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:myEAGLContext options:contextOptions];

CGImageRef outputCGImage = [context createCGImage:blendOutput fromRect:[blendOutput extent]];
UIImage * outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputCGImage];
CGImageRelease(outputCGImage);

return outputImage;}
```

Comment: Did you profile this code? I'll wager the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`/`UIGraphicsEndImageContext` pair is a substantial cost owing to the memory allocation behind it. You could do pretty well just not creating and destroying a brand new context for every composition.

Comment: The issues is not memory, That actually stays quite low the issue is CPU that jumps from 20% up to 95% when I am overlaying the image into the video frame then sending it through RTMP.  I was hoping to get it on the GPU to try to keep the cpu low as when it does get up to 95% mark it messes with the rate at which the video frames are compressed.

Comment: I'm wagering it's a substantial processing cost. Memory allocation implies synchronisation and OS-internal non-O(1) structure adjustments. Just suggesting that switching to the GPU may be a very blunt way of solving the problem. You should also profile to check out how much that `[UIImage imageNamed:]` is costing — `imageNamed:` is subject to a cache but that just means that it may be fast, not that it definitely will be.

Comment: I have messed around with changing [UIImage ImageNmed:] to a global variable and it did not help it.  Currently that code gets the job done and its the rough draft I am definitely looking for ways to make it more memory efficient later on but primarily it needs to be CPU efficient as the high CPU usage messes with the streaming capability of app causing what looks like a back up from the audio/video encoding.  My thought going to the GPU would be to eliminate the high processing on CPU so encoding stays at normal rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest performance issue is that each frame you create **EAGLContext** and **CIContext**. This needs to be done only once outside of your processUsingCoreImage method.

Also if you want to avoid the CPU-GPU roundtrip, instead of creating a Core Graphics image (createCGImage ) thus Cpu processing you can render directly in EaglLayer like this  :

```
[context drawImage:blendOutput inRect: fromRect: ];
[myEaglContext presentRenderBuffer:G:_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply It turns out that  [self createPaddedGhostImageWithSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720)] was a huge cause of the cpu spike so i made it only create the image once and then it helped a lot.  I also changed it to reuse the EAGLContext as a global variable I will also try out it on the CIContext to see if it lowers it more. OpenGL seems like the way to go but its over my head let me look into eagllayer.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions in order:

1. do you really need to composite the two images? Is an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` with a `UIImageView` on top insufficient? You'd then just apply the current ghost transform to the image view (or its layer) and let the compositor glue the two together, for which it will use the GPU.
2. if not then first port of call should be CoreImage — it wraps up GPU image operations into a relatively easy Swift/Objective-C package. There is a simple composition filter so all you need to do is make the two things into `CIImage`s and use `-imageByApplyingTransform:` to adjust the ghost.
3. failing both of those, then you're looking at an OpenGL solution. You specifically want to use `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` to push core video frames to the GPU, and the ghost will simply permanently live there. Start from the [GLCameraRipple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) as to that stuff, then look into `GLKBaseEffect` to save yourself from needing to know GLSL if you don't already. All you should need to do is package up some vertices and make a drawing call.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately its not that simple, its streaming video frames so I can't just put a UIImageView on top i need a new frame containing both overlays so that it shows up on stream as well instead of for just the broadcaster.    2.  I did switch it over to core image last night, (I will update the code above to show it) but it still does not seem to be on the GPU it shows 0 FPS in my Profiler as well as High CPU is still present.  3. I look into that I don't know GLSL but always up for a challenge, and look at whats on there it seems to be in the right direction I need!